# Xubuntu 19.10 can't mount XFS partitions

Tags: partitioning, mount, xubuntu, hard-drive, xfs

Have a machine with Xubuntu 19.10 on it.  I previously formatted a drive with EXT4 and had no problems mounting it (i put it in FSTAB)

I decided I wanted XFS on it as it was previously an XFS drive and it worked well for me (also seems to provide more available space than EXT4 - that i think is due to how inodes work in each file system).

at first I could not format the drive XFS with `sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb` as it seemed the binary was not in the path.

I tried to `locate mkfs.xfs` but it did not exist.

So I installed XFS
`sudo apt install xfsprogs`

I also made sure to remove all references to the drive in /etc/fstab
`sudo nano /etc/fstab`

now i was able to format the drive to XFS
`sudo mkfs.xfs /dev/sdb`

no problem formatting it (also in gnome-disks shows up as XFS) so now i attempt to mount it
`sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media/Backup`

Does not provide an error but also does not succeed in mounting it.

I try also to put it into /etc/fstab with gnome-disks default options and reboot. Still will not mount the drive.

I guess my other options would be to stick with EXT4 (and limit the files I can backup on my main computer when I rsync) or to switch to Ubuntu MATE which seems to have this XFS stuff  built in.

Could anyone tell me why I can't mount this drive in Xubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

ok so not sure what happened but I got it to work.
I cleared off the old partition by running `sudo fdisk /dev/sdb` and hitting d to delete the only partition. then I chose the option to create a new blank "dos" partition, hit w to write changes to disk.

I fired up gnome-disks and created a new XFS partition on the disk.  Was able to mount it, and then set it up in FSTAB using the gnome-disk tool.  Rebooted and the drive was mounted and am now able to copy files to it.